# How to resolve tie in LEAD or LAG analytical functions if we have duplicate values in ordered set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with with records as :

```
VERSION_ID    START_DATE
Vrandom1      2018-03-22
Vrandom2      2018-03-22
```

When I run SQL :

```
SELECT T.VERSION_ID VERSION_ID, 
START_DATE,
LEAD  (START_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) LEAD_START_DATE
FROM TABLE T
```

I get :

```
VERSION_ID    START_DATE                   LEAD_START_DATE
Vrandom1      2018-03-22                   2018-03-22
Vrandom2      2018-03-22                   NULL
```

What is correct SQL to get correct leading values ?

I would expect null as LEAD_START_DATE for both records or same value of LEAD_START_DATE for both records.  Thanks

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is wrong.  `ORDER BY` in SQL is *unstable* meaning that the ordering is arbitrary when keys have the same value.  Even calling `ORDER BY` twice in the same query can produce different results -- and that is what you are seeing.

The "correct" version would be to *expect* different results and make the ordering stable by introducing a new key:

```
SELECT T.VERSION_ID VERSION_ID, START_DATE,
       LEAD(START_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE, VERSION_ID) as LEAD_START_DATE
FROM TABLE T;
```

But that doesn't solve your problem.

Offhand, what comes to mind is trying different leads, but this gets confusing because `NULL` usually indicates the last value.  Instead, I would change your expectation and introduce a stable sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is unfounded.

Some analytical functions, LEAD() being one of them, requires a total ordering of the rows, and will not handle ties differently from non-ties. As you have seen. The result in this case is *non-deterministic*.

Some, but not all, analytic functions allow you to specify a WINDOW. LEAD() does not. For those functions that do allow a window, you can specify a physical offset (which - from the point of view of the problem at hand - doesn't help, since it still requires a total ordering of all the rows, with no special handling for ties) or a LOGICAL offset, where ties are treated exactly as you wish.

One such function that you could use is FIRST_VALUE. You need to make sure the window starts after the current row, but the starting offset is not so great that it will also miss rows with different values in the relevant column. So, for example, if your START_DATE column is of data type `date`, you know that increments are 1 second or more. So, you could use something like

```
.......

, FIRST_VALUE(START_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE 
                  RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' SECOND FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```